# When should one prefer Mahout's SequentialAccessSparseVector over RandomAccessSparseVector?

Tags: mahout

I'm a newbie with regards to mahout. I would like to build my own algorithms with mahout's tools. I'm quite puzzled with the of usage Mahout's `SequentialAccessSparseVector` and `RandomAccessSparseVector`. Could someone suggest when should one prefer over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random-access version is backed by a hashtable, which will have the fastest sets and gets. But the iteration order is undefined. Sometimes iterating over vectors in order of dimension makes other operations efficient, like in computing a dot product, which only needs to look at the dimensions where both are defined. It will have slightly slower sets and gets and maybe use a little more memory. Both are sparse representations though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sean, it helped me understand when to use them. Its that we should use SequentialAccessSparseVector when we need  to perform an operation where we require to iterate by the order of index and not randomly, since it cost O(n) for write. Thanks again

Comment: Should be O(log n) for read and write since it's backed by a tree.

Comment: But the following documentation says it takes o(n) for write [link](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-math/org/apache/mahout/math/SequentialAccessSparseVector.html). In MIA's appendix section for vectors, it's been said that the problem of RandomAccessSparseVector can be solved with a tree or similar structure that can handle ordered mapping. And it also adds it comes with a cost of longer access time. So I thought that writing to SequentialAccessSparseVector was similar to writing to ordered arrays(index and value), where writing at the front would require O(n).

Comment: I think that's right actually -- I looked at the code and it uses an array structure, which makes a set O(n) in the worst case. I looked at MiA again and the appendix says the sequential-access version can use a tree for sequential access, not random -- wouldn't make sense otherwise.